# Apache Cordova App allow external scripts

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, content-security-policy

I am currently building an apache cordova mobile app through visual studio and have run into the problem of trying to run widgets through external scripts in my app.  These scripts run fine in the browser simulator but once I try to run them on an apple device, the scripts do not load.  I have researched into this problem and found that it usually has something to do with the content security policy, which I have attached below to help figure out the problem.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

What else could possibly be the problem as to why these widgets are not loading in my app?  These are the scripts I am attempting to load inside of my app for your reference as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rf.revolvermaps.com/0/0/8.js?i=5tfq2n8w5rc&amp;m=0c&amp;c=cbb677&amp;cr1=ffffff&amp;f=calibri&amp;l=0&amp;cw=ffffff&amp;cb=450084" async="async"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rf.revolvermaps.com/0/0/0.js?i=5gbey55pbu3&amp;d=2&amp;p=1&amp;b=1&amp;w=293&amp;g=1&amp;f=calibri&amp;fs=12&amp;r=0&amp;c0=362b05&amp;c1=450084&amp;c2=000000&amp;ic0=0&amp;ic1=0" async="async"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you a whitelist for online ressources?

A better approach would be to embed these ressources. Loading online scripts is really insecure. The server could send js, and get acces to you device through the cordova api.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/de/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/

Comment: What if I control the server and the JS resource? No security implications then, right?

Comment: In the question are three different domains mentioned. I assumed they aren't all from the author.

Comment: Thats fine - I was actually just asking because I really wanted to know your opinion :-)

Comment: As long as the server is not compromised, everything is fine. But Apple or Google may unlist the app, because of the loading of online scripts, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

Your src and href from the script and link tags should have an scheme (http or https), otherwise, when Cordova finds //, it will use it's default scheme, file:.

Add http: or https: to all your script and link tags and then it should work.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rf.revolvermaps.com/0/0/8.js?i=5tfq2n8w5rc&amp;m=0c&amp;c=cbb677&amp;cr1=ffffff&amp;f=calibri&amp;l=0&amp;cw=ffffff&amp;cb=450084" async="async"></script>
```

Comment: So that worked for all of my links except for the revolvermaps links.  The app still won't display the 2 revolvermaps scripts.

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code?

Comment: @Roger99 the problem is in the scripts, they make other requests to other revolvemaps scripts and it's not adding http: or https: to them, so file: is used. I don't think you can do something about it